# the use of 'were' and 'was' when describing a situation

Tags: american-english

What is the correct use of 'were' and 'was' in an imaginary sentence such as:

''If I were to go biking I would be tired.''

How is this different from the sentences below:

If I go biking I will be tired,
or
If I bike, I get tired.

Does a sentence such as
''If I was to go biking, I would be tired'' make more sense?

Comment: "Were" and "was" are interchangeable. This "were" is called the 'irrealis' mood form, an untidy relic of an earlier system, unique to "be", and limited to the 1st and 3rd person singular. "Were" is somewhat more formal than "was", and some speakers usually, if not always, use preterite "was" instead.

Comment: All of the sentences you give are grammatical, all of them make sense, and all of them can describe the same situation, though they don't all mean quite the same things. Oh, and it doesn't matter whether you use _were_ or _was_ in this construction.

Comment: Your first sentence is a hypothesis, your second a prediction.